# BodyMassIndex calculator error (NaN)

Tags: java, nan

I am getting a NaN error when I compile this, i can't figure out what I am doing wrong? I tried moving the variables around to see if I could get them working but nothing. Notice the variable I put of type double i used for bmi after inches = keyboard.nextInt(); I think its a divide by zero error but i dont know what i am dividing by zero.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BodyMassIndex {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int pounds =0;      
    int feet = 0;
    int inches = 0;
    double heightMeters = ((feet * 12) + inches) * .0254;
    double mass = pounds / 2.2; 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds");
    pounds = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter how many feet you are");
    feet = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter how many inches after feet");
    inches = keyboard.nextInt();
    double bmi = mass / (heightMeters * heightMeters);

    System.out.println(mass);
    System.out.println(bmi);

    if(bmi < 18.5){
        System.out.println("Underweight");
    }
    else if ((bmi >= 18.5) && (bmi < 25)){
        System.out.println("Normal weight");
    }
    else if ((bmi >= 25) && (bmi < 30))
        System.out.println("Above weight");
    else
        System.out.println("Obese");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please try [duck debugging](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/) and other basics before just asking here. Asking for us to debug your program is a terrible way to get anything done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the dynamic nature of your variables, such that when you type

`double heightMeters = ((feet * 12) + inches) * .0254;`

This assignment is immediately evaluated using the current values of `feet` and `inches` (which are `0` at that moment), before any of the keyboard entry is performed. To perform these calculations with the values entered by the keyboard, these calculations need to be performed and their results assigned to their corresponding variables **after** the keyboard entry is done, when the current values of `pounds`, `feet` and `inches` are what you just entered. Because `heightMeters` is still zero from its initialization and hasn't been changed since, you're getting a divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the exception because the value of heightMeters is 0 here:

```
double bmi = mass / (heightMeters * heightMeters);
```

The only time that heightMeters is calculated, the result of it is 0:

```
double heightMeters = ((feet * 12) + inches) * .0254;
```

It looks like you want to use this calculation, so I'd split it into a separate function:

```
public static double getHeightInMeters(int feet, int inches)
{
    return 0.0254 * ((feet * 12) + inches);
}
```

Then you can call it later:

```
double heightMeters = this.getHeightInMeters(feet, inches);
double bmi = mass / (heightMeters * heightMeters);
```